# Proving inequality involving the exponential function

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality (which I think is true) that

$$
1 - e^{-x} \leq e^{-e^{-x}}
$$

Unfortunately I'm not making very much progress. My first thoughts were that

$$
\begin{align}
1- e^{-x}
&\leq -e^{-x} \\
&\leq e^{-x}
\end{align}
$$

but unfortunately this is not always less than $e^{-e^{-x}}$ so this line of thought doesn't really work.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

For any $z$, $e^{-z} \geq 1 - z$. Substitute $z = e^{-x}$, we find $e^{-e^{-x}} \geq 1 - e^{-x}$.

Comment: Actually, the inequality $e^{-z}\ge1-z$ holds for every real number.

Comment: @Another User You are right. Thank you.

Comment: very clean answer. +1.